# Serverless Lambda Cognito environment variables being imported as objects

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, serverless

My Serverless YML creates a Cognito Pool & Client

```
resources:
  Resources:
    CognitoUserPool:
      Type: "AWS::Cognito::UserPool"
      Properties:
        UserPoolName: ${self:provider.stage}_pool
        AccountRecoverySetting:
          RecoveryMechanisms:
            - Name: verified_email
              Priority: 1
            - Name: verified_phone_number
              Priority: 2
        AdminCreateUserConfig:
          UnusedAccountValidityDays: 30
        AutoVerifiedAttributes:
          - email
        UsernameAttributes:
          - email
          - phone_number
        MfaConfiguration: OFF
        Policies:
          PasswordPolicy:
            MinimumLength: 8
            RequireLowercase: True
            RequireNumbers: True
            RequireSymbols: True
            RequireUppercase: True
        Schema:
          - Name: email
            AttributeDataType: String
            Mutable: false
            Required: true
        UserPoolTags:
          env: ${self:provider.stage}
    CognitoUserPoolClient:
      Type: "AWS::Cognito::UserPoolClient"
      DependsOn:
        - CognitoUserPoolIdentityProvider
      Properties:
        AllowedOAuthFlows:
          - code
          - implicit
        AllowedOAuthFlowsUserPoolClient: true
        AllowedOAuthScopes:
          - email
          - profile
          - phone
          - openid
          - aws.cognito.signin.user.admin
        CallbackURLs:
          - http://localhost:3000/oauth/login
        ClientName: ${self:provider.stage}_retailer_client
        EnableTokenRevocation: true
        ExplicitAuthFlows:
          - ALLOW_ADMIN_USER_PASSWORD_AUTH
          - ALLOW_CUSTOM_AUTH
          - ALLOW_REFRESH_TOKEN_AUTH
          - ALLOW_USER_PASSWORD_AUTH
          - ALLOW_USER_SRP_AUTH
        GenerateSecret: False
        LogoutURLs:
          - http://localhost:3000/oauth/logout
        PreventUserExistenceErrors: LEGACY
        SupportedIdentityProviders: [ "COGNITO", "Google" ]
        UserPoolId:
          Ref: CognitoUserPool
    CognitoUserPoolDomain:
      Type: "AWS::Cognito::UserPoolDomain"
      Properties:
        CustomDomainConfig:
          CertificateArn: arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:256645674595:certificate/b6bd7asd1-a8ca-6d19-92a2-cf1s4fsa9a3ha
        Domain: "auth.whatnerds.com"
        UserPoolId:
          Ref: CognitoUserPool
    CognitoUserPoolIdentityProvider:
      Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPoolIdentityProvider
      Properties:
        ProviderName: Google
        AttributeMapping:
          email: email
          email_verified: email_verified
          family_name: family_name
          given_name: given_name
          name: name
          username: sub
        ProviderDetails:
          client_id: CLIENT_ID
          client_secret: SECRET_ID
          authorize_scopes: profile email openid
        ProviderType: Google
        UserPoolId:
          Ref: CognitoUserPool
```

I'm trying to export my User Pool ID and User Pool Client ID to my lambda's through the environment parameter:

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  environment:
    USER_POOL_ID: !Ref CognitoUserPool
    CLIENT_ID: !Ref CognitoUserPoolClient
    REGION: ca-central-1a
```

My Lambda Environment Configuration looks like this:

[Lambda Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVS9C.png)

My Response from my lambda call is throwing an error where the UserPool ID and Client ID are being read as [object Object] and throwing an error.

[Debug Serverless Offline CLI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1wGH.png)

Chrome Error:

```
{"message":"2 validation errors detected: Value '[object Object]' at 'clientId' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [\\w+]+; Value '[object Object]' at 'userPoolId' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [\\w-]+_[0-9a-zA-Z]+","code":"InvalidParameterException","time":"2022-06-25T15:39:58.851Z","requestId":"5b1ad21d-218a-4cd0-9475-f89b8ec1fc28","statusCode":400,"retryable":false,"retryDelay":49.39420786096056}
```

Any suggestions to what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: did you find any work-around for this?

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because the USER_POOL_ID and CLIENT_ID are referenced before they are created.

It is not possible to reference CloudFormation Outputs in serverless.yml because it creates a circular dependency as someone notes in this serverless forum.

https://forum.serverless.com/t/can-i-access-outputs-from-custom-resources-as-variables-in-serverless-yml/508/10

You can overcome this by using cross-stack references.

First, create your CognitoUserPool and CognitoUserPoolClient in another stack and export their ids as output. Then in your stack with the authorizer reference the outputs as you normally would.

[This article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-cloudformation-update-yaml-cross-stack-references-simplified-substitution/) contains a good explanation of cross-stack references and how to use them.